# Jquery datatables look weird

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

does anybody know what my datatable looks this weird? I know it should be something trivial, but i just can not figure it out and it's bugging me all day. The sample data is data found on http://datatables.net/ (shamelessly copied 1:1 so this should not be a problem). I'm not overwriting by accident any default css rules and i didn't edit the default jquery theme flick.

This is how i initialize my datatable:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({ 
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bSaveState": true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        {'sWidth':'40px', 'aTargets':[0]},
        {'sWidth':'350px', 'aTargets':[1]},
        {'sWidth':'350px', 'aTargets':[2]}
    ]});
```

this is how my `<header>` looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/css3.css" />
```

screenshot of the datatable how it looks:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: aaaa, i forgot that i need the line `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo_table_jui.css" />` for it to work... but still the sorting arrows are still weirdly possitioned :/

Comment: The cell borders can be fixed with `<table .. cellpadding="0" border="0" cellspacing="0">`, which makes it so that lines are horizontal. And thanks, your `<table .. class="display"> solution works for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i figured it out, for future reference, you **need** the `class='display'` bit in the `<table>` tag without it the default look will not work.

and later you also need

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo_table_jui.css" />
```

Comment: This also fixed my issue with sort arrows being on a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're setting the first column to 40px wide:

```
{'sWidth':'40px', 'aTargets':[0]},
```

but **Rendering engine** is a bit wider than 40px, that forces your header row to wrap to more than one line and ugliness happens.

The odd looking paging links at the bottom looks like you missed some CSS while copying.